# passing data in javascript innerhtml to database

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

> document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'choice 1:  type="text" name="choice" value="">

Does anybody knows how to pass the name="choice" to database?

i got an undefined index choice error.

Comment: you'll need to provide much more information. what database, whats your ajax call look like, do you have  a rest api you are using? what server lang?

Comment: localhost phpmyadmin database,i do not have ajax function as i only know  basic html and php coding.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a huge question there but to try and help, the workflow might be:

```
1. post your data using ajax to a serverside handler
2. process and validate/sanitise the data and pass it to the database
3. once done return a confirmation (or error) message back tot he frontend
4. handle the ajax response and feedback to the user
```

here is some [information about ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), here's the php manual [docs on pdo and mysql database functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and here is the docs for [jquery which might make the ajax process a big easyer](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Give the resources a read, have a go at implementing the functionality you need and if you get stuck post smaller, recreatable problems with the code you have written

Answer (score 0):

You have to create form in you innreHTML. For ex,
In your JavaScript,

```
var display="<form action='url' method='post'>"+
 "<input type='text' name='Name'/>"+
 "<input type='submit' name='Submit'/>"+
 "</form>";
```

Then, you can add this text box value into database at another JSP page code by using JSTL tags.